# Draw canvas with avoidxfermode

Tags: android, android-canvas

This is my first post.
I'm developing a drawing application for Android and are opposite to a problem that I can not fix.
I have an image with various geometric shapes also superimposed. Each has a different colored geometric shapes.
With Avoidxfermode I can draw on the form with a specific color.
Now I would like the colorful picture is not visible to the user.
In practice I would recognize the area in which color through the colored picture, but I would like the new color to appear on a white image

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question, maybe with pictures. I can't make head or tail of it.

Comment: I Can't add an image because I  I do not have enough reputation! :(

Comment: Ok, then try to describe *what you are trying to do* in more detail. All I understand is that you have an image with smaller images of various shapes superimposed on top of it. I don't understand what your *goal* is, i.e. what you are using AvoidXferMode *for*. What sort of app is it? Whats the user trying to do?

Comment: Thank you and I apologize for how I asked the question.
In practice I have a bitmap on which we have drawn a rectangle and a circle.
Red Rectangle, Circle Blue and white background.
With Avoidxfermode, target mode, I can paint with finger on the red rectangle without going out of bounds.
But I would like to show you the white rectangle and the circle and then color them with reference to the method described above.

Comment: Forget AvoidXferMode for a moment. When the user drags their finger across the image, what is the expectation? That it *erases* the red rectangle, but leaves everything else alone?

Comment: With the finger i want color che rectangle and leave the rest unchanged. The problem is that I can have some more complicated shapes (like a star).

Comment: You want the rectangle (and only the rectangle) to change colour, but only those pixels the user touches?

Comment: That's right. Practically with ACTION_DOWN touch the rectangle and choose my area.
With ACTION_MOVE should not draw my path if it goes out of the rectangle.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to operate on color values alone. Sounds to me like you want two images - one containing just the thing you are modifying (the rectangle) and one containing everything else. Let the user's finger only affect the first one. For ACTION_MOVE try drawing a small filled circle using a Paint with a ColorFilter.

Comment: My problem is how to get the image with only the rectangle or any other form.
My initial bitmap varied and there are no precise shapes to use as a pattern.

Comment: So the rectangle isn't actually a separate superimposed image at all?

Comment: ehhehehehe. The shape are part of the original image. So I wanted to use colors to distinguish them.